# Rust trait with "simple" and "advanced" versions

Tags: rust, traits, api-design

I have two traits which are basically equivalent, but one provides a lower level interface than the other.  Given the higher level trait, one can easily implement the lower level trait.  I want to write a library which accepts an implementation of either trait.

My specific case is a trait for traversing a tree:

```
// "Lower level" version of the trait
pub trait RawState {
    type Cost: std::cmp::Ord + std::ops::Add<Output = Self::Cost> + std::marker::Copy;
    type CulledChildrenIterator: Iterator<Item = (Self, Self::Cost)>;
    fn cull(&self) -> Option<Self::Cost>;
    fn children_with_cull(&self) -> Self::CulledChildrenIterator;
}
// "Higher level" version of the trait
pub trait State: RawState {
    type ChildrenIterator: Iterator<Item = (Self, Self::Cost)>;
    fn children(&self) -> Self::ChildrenIterator;
}

// Example of how RawState could be implemented using State
fn state_children_with_cull<S: State> (s: S)
     -> impl Iterator<Item = (S, S::Cost)> 
{
    s.children()
      .filter_map(move |(state, transition_cost)|
         state.cull().map(move |emission_cost|
            (state, transition_cost + emission_cost)
         )
      )
}
```

Here, State trait provides an interface where you define the .children() function to list the children, and the `.cull()` function to potentially cull a state.

The `RawState` trait provides an interface where you define a function `.children_with_cull()` instead, which iterates through the children and culls them in a single function call.  This allows an implementation of `RawState` to never even generate children that it knows will be culled.

I would like to allow most users to only implement the `State` trait, and have the `RawState` implementation be automatically generated based on their State implementation.  However, when implementing `State`, some parts of the trait are still a part of `RawState`, e.g.

```
#[derive(Clone, Eq, PartialEq, Hash, Debug)]
struct DummyState {}

impl State for DummyState {
    type Cost = u32;
    type ChildrenIterator = DummyIt;
    fn emission(&self) -> Option<Self::Cost> {
        Some(0u32)
    }
    fn children(&self) -> DummyIt {
        return DummyIt {};
    }
}
```

Will give errors, because the type "Cost" is defined in RawState, not in State.  On potential workaround, to redefine all the relevant parts of the RawState inside State, i.e. define State as

```
pub trait State: RawState {
    type Cost: std::cmp::Ord + std::ops::Add<Output = Self::Cost> + std::marker::Copy;
    type ChildrenIterator: Iterator<Item = (Self, Self::Cost)>;
    fn cull(&self) -> Option<Self::Cost>;
    fn children(&self) -> Self::ChildrenIterator;
}
```

But then the compiler will complain about the ambiguous duplicate definitions. For example in the `DummyState` implementation for `State`, it will complain that `Self::Cost` is ambiguous, since it can't tell whether you are referring to `<Self as State>::Cost`, or `<Self as RawState>::Cost`.

Comment: Are you sure you need two traits, and not just one trait with a [default implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/traits.html#default-methods) of `children_with_cull`?

Comment: @trentcl: Those types that would rather implement `RawState` directly would still have to implement `children`, even though `children` is not used directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considering that both `RawState` and `State` are not [object-safe](https://huonw.github.io/blog/2015/01/object-safety/) (because they use `Self` in return types), I'll assume that you don't intend to create trait objects for these traits (i.e. no `&RawState`).

The supertrait bound `State: RawState` is mostly important when dealing with trait objects, because trait objects can only specify one trait (plus a select few whitelisted traits from the standard library that have no methods, like `Copy`, `Send` and `Sync`). The vtable that the trait object refers to only contains pointers to the methods defined in that trait. But if the trait has supertrait bounds, then the methods from those traits are also included in the vtable. Thus, a `&State` (if it was legal) would give you access to `children_with_cull`.

Another situation where the supertrait bound is important is when the subtrait provides default implementations for some methods. The default implementation can make use of the supertrait bound to access methods from another trait.

Since you can't use trait objects, and since you don't have default implementations for the methods in `State`, I think that you should simply not declare the supertrait bound `State: RawState`, because it adds nothing (and indeed, causes issues).

With this approach, it becomes necessary to copy the members from `RawState` that we need to implement `State`, as you suggested. `State` would thus be defined like this:

```
pub trait State: Sized {
    type Cost: std::cmp::Ord + std::ops::Add<Output = Self::Cost> + std::marker::Copy;
    type ChildrenIterator: Iterator<Item = (Self, Self::Cost)>;

    fn cull(&self) -> Option<Self::Cost>;
    fn children(&self) -> Self::ChildrenIterator;
}
```

(Note that the bound `State: Sized` is required because we use `Self` in `ChildrenIterator`. `RawState` also need the bound `RawState: Sized`.)

Finally, we can provide a blanket `impl` of `RawState` for all types that implement `State`. With this `impl`, any type that implements `State` will automatically implement `RawState`.

```
impl<T> RawState for T
where
    T: State
{
    type Cost = <Self as State>::Cost;
    type CulledChildrenIterator = std::iter::Empty<(Self, Self::Cost)>; // placeholder

    fn cull(&self) -> Option<Self::Cost> { <Self as State>::cull(self) }
    fn children_with_cull(&self) -> Self::CulledChildrenIterator {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

Note the syntax to disambiguate the conflicting names: `<Self as State>`. It's used on the two members we duplicated so that `RawState` defers to `State`.

Comment: Very cool! Exactly what I'm looking for.  I will need to read up on object-safety, but I think my code works fine because my library uses templated functions instead of trait-objects.